# Unable to initialise firebase in my html file and save any data to realtime database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to learn firebase. But i am unable to save my input to the firebase database because it is not getting initialized even after adding all the required script that I know. Here is my entire code
PS: authentication to my database was also turned off for learning purpose. So it must not be any issue with authentication.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning Firebase</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">                 
    var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxx"
          };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var text=documentgetElementById('text').value;

    function validate(){

          var database=firebase.database().ref();
          database.child("text").set(text);

       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="validate();">
       Text:<input type="text" id='text'/>
       <input type='submit' value='save'/>
    </form>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with your Firebase code, it is about your JavaScript code. Replace this code below and try it again:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning Firebase</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">                 
    var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxx",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxx"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);   

    function validate(){    
          var yourNewChildValue=document.getElementById('text').value;
          var database=firebase.database().ref();
          database.child("yourNewChildKey").set(yourNewChildValue);
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
       Text:<input type="text" id='text'/>
       <input type='button' onclick="validate();" value='save'/>
    </form>  
</body>
```

It must be save your data to Firebase database if your credentials are true. Please let me know.

Comment: wow! thanks a lot .It worked .
so getting the element should be done inside the function ,right?

Comment: Your welcome. Yes, it needed to be in function and one more detail we can talk about it. You don't need a post back, because you are using Firebase and there is no need form element's submit action, so we triggered function via button onclick event. Your Firebase code is true.